# What chart type can display 8 scores together with averages per subsets of scores?

Tags: r, excel, charts

I'm looking for a chart that can display the following data:

```
Nanoentities    LoC   Dependencies  SCC   Entities  Responsibilities    Relations   Semantic
2.9             0.0   10.0          10.0  3.0       2.9                 6.7         7.6
```

Until now a simple column chart would do! Yet, I still need to show the average per attribute (which can be grouped as follows):

```
Granularity=AVG(Nanoentities,LoC)
Coupling=AVG(Dependencies,SCC)
Cohesion=AVG(Entities,Responsibilities,Relations,Semantic)
```

in the same chart. 
What type of chart would better represent this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for another possibilty to display your chart rather than in bar plots.
You can use the `plotly` or `ggplot` function to do so.

Like on this [site](https://www.mailman.columbia.edu/sites/default/files/media/fdawg_ggplot2.html) you can display your numbers by setting different factors. If you just want to display one variable against another a scatterplot can be used like this: 
     `#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
plot(x=iris$Sepal.Length, y=iris$Sepal.Width, xlab="Sepal Length", ylab="Sepal Width", main="Sepal Length-Width")`

You just have to exchange the `x` and `y` values for your parts of data,`xlab` and `ylab` describe the axes and `main` is for the chart title.
For more charts just search for them (see the link above for their names and how they look) and see example codes for them in the individual package.

Comment: Thanks, @Capt.Krusty! B) is what I'm trying to ask. I am wondering what type of chart would be better suited for displaying a series of scores with categories that group the scores via calculating the average of the tests contained in that category.

Comment: I updated my answer. Often it is easier to look for a diagramm or chart that looks like your desired result and search for code or package examples with the image. Where there's an image, there's code nearby ;)

Comment: An upvote would be nice if my answer helped you out ;)

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your response already, however it is not visible due to my low reputation... Thanks for your answer! It was useful!

Answer (score 0):

A multicategory bar/line combo should do the trick.

[image]